# How can I set the text on the right of a glyphicon into a Twitter BootStrap theme?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, glyphicons

I am pretty new in Twitter BootStrap and I have the following problem:

I have defined this section into my page:

```
    <!-- Column 3:  -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="group-item">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
              <h4><a href="#">TEST</a></h4>
              <p>Bla Bla Bla</p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

So I want that the **i** tag that show the BootStrap **glyphicon** is on the left and that the thext (TEST and Bla Bla Bla) is on the right.

So I am trying to set the following CSS:

```
.groups i {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 80px;
}
```

But it can't work and I obtain that the text is under the glyphicon.

Why? What am I missing? How can I fix this issue?

Tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most obvious solution is to move the glyph into the link.

```css
.group-item i {
  margin-right: .5em; /* margin to tast */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="group-item">
              <h4><a href="#"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>TEST</a></h4>
              <p>Bla Bla Bla</p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

This has the added benefit of making the icon clickable.

Alternatively, just float the icon

```css
.group-item i {
  float: left;
  margin-right: .5em;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="group-item">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></i>
      <h4><a href="#">TEST</a></h4>
      <p>Bla Bla Bla</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

just applying float:left to the graphic icon you can achieve this

you are not missing any thing but the thing is that for the **.glyphicon** in bootstrap uses **inline-block** and you can understand the this thing by given js fiddle

**[Understanding](http://jsfiddle.net/Mta2b/)**
reference js fiddle

```css
.groups i {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    width: 80px;
}
.test{
    float:left;
}
```

```html
   <!-- Column 3:  -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="group-item">
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-home test"></i>
              <h4><a href="#">TEST</a></h4>
              <p>Bla Bla Bla</p>
            </div>
    </div>
```

here is demo

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/15b35m5f/)**

Comment: @AndreaNobili please check out the answer